# How to prevent debugger from breaking when ArgumentException is thrown when using ValidatesOnExceptions=true in WPF

Tags: wpf, validation, data-binding

I am using the ValidatesOnExceptions=true method of WPF validation. This involves throwing an exception in the source's property setter method. It works but the debugger always breaks when the exception is thrown. I am guessing that this is because the exception is not caught directly in my user code but it is caught in the WPF validation code. Is there anyway to stop the behavior, or is it just the price you pay when you use this method of validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio go to Debug - Exceptions... and uncheck User-unhandled

I think Tools - Options... - Debugging - General - "Enable just my Code" must be checked for this option to be visible

If you want to disable breaking on a specific exception, say System.Exception, then Expand System and uncheck System.Exception

Comment: Doesn't this disable the debugger to break on *every* unhandled exception? That would be a major loss of debugging functionality which should really be noted with such advice.

Comment: @LonelyPixel: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. It prevents the debugger to break on every user-unhandled exception of the specific unchecked type. Do you want to be able to set this in certain scopes?

Comment: Well, normally, when I leave an ("unexpected") exception unhandled in my code, that is a bug which would normally lead to a crash of the application. I find it very convenient that a debugger catches them and points me to the offending code line. If this is disabled completely, it would be a great loss. (Guess I'll just test it myself tomorrow.)

Comment: @LonelyPixel: For WPF Bindings, Exceptions in the property setter gets handled by the framework. If the exception doesn't get handled by the framework (when the setter gets called from code for example) you'll still get notified unless the exception is handled. However, we've had a lot of unexcepted and hard to track down bugs caused by exceptions in setters which were swallowed by the framework. So most of the time, I just leave "break on exception" on.